# cannot update fields in the MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to update a field in MySQL database but I'm getting an error.

This is my Query

```
UPDATE tbl SET fl1="val",fl2="val", fl3="val" WHERE fl0="val val"
```

This is the error I received when I tried to execute the query

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'val WHEREfl0="val val"' at line 1
```

I have removed the information from the query and replaced it with dummy text.

Comment: WHEREfl0 is surely wrong (should be WHERE fl0), are you sure that this is the error you are given?

Comment: check that there is a space between WHERE & f10 in your original query. `'val WHEREfl0="val val"'`

Comment: yes!! and there is a [SPACE] between them!

Comment: yea I see a space and I do not see that this was edited

Comment: Can we have the structure of the table, as this will help answer your question

Comment: I wouldn't replace your actual issue with dummy text because in doing so you are adding in the possibility of re-typing / changing the query incorrectly.  Please give us the actual issue with the actual query.

Comment: We can't really say what's wrong, because you removed the information we need. There's something not right just before `val WHEREf l0` and we'd need to see it.

Comment: Does your dummy text query work?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post the actual data as this is sensitive data!

Comment: please all, check my answer below, I found the problem and solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND IT :D ... I'm having multiple queries to be executed, this is done using PHP ... The problem was in a query in the middle was like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET fl1='val',fl2='val', fl3=''val WHERE fl0='val val'
```

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR SUPPORT.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the error, I see 2 issues

```
val WHEREfl0="val val"
```

- first of all, `WHEREfl0` should probably be `WHERE fl0`
- Secondly an issue here `val WHERE[..]` I think you are missing `"` there.

`val" WHERE fl0="val val"`

I am guessing you fixed the query while adding dummy text because this query is correct:

```
UPDATE tbl SET fl1="val",fl2="val", fl3="val" WHERE fl0="val val"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes, not double. ('')

`UPDATE tbl SET fl1='val',fl2=val', fl3='val' WHERE fl0='val val'`

You should also use the "`" in your syntax:

```
UPDATE `tbl` SET `fl1`='val',`fl2`=val', `fl3`='val' WHERE `fl0`='val val'
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
UPDATE `tbl` 
   SET `fl1` = 'val',
       `fl2` = 'val', 
       `fl3` = 'val' 
 WHERE `fl0` = 'val val'
```

1.) I have changed Double Quote into Apostrophe.

2.) I added `backtick` in case one of your columns contains a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).